# How to restrict a clipped image within a rectangle in Fabric js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am working on a project using Fabric.js and I need to implement a feature where I can change the shape of an image to a circle (or any shape) and restrict it to appear only within a rectangle object (if the image is dragged outside the rectangle, that part should not be visible).

I have already looked into the Fabric.js documentation, but I couldn't find a clear example or instructions on how to achieve this specific functionality. I can change the shape of the image to a circle using clipPath but I cannot restrict it to only appear within a rect.

Could someone please guide me on how to accomplish this task in Fabric.js? Any help or code samples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

So far I have the following code that clips the image into a circle on the fabric's [kitchensink](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink) site:

```
canvas.clear();

new fabric.Image.fromURL('https://images.pexels.com/photos/17041911/pexels-photo-17041911.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2', function(img) {
  img.scaleToWidth(300)
  
 const container = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100, 
  top: 100, 
  width: 600,  
  height:300,
  fill: 'green'
  opacity: .2
});

 const circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 400,
 originX: "center",
 originY:"center"
})


img.set("clipPath", circle)


canvas.add(container)
canvas.add(img)

canvas.renderAll();
});
```